app inspector cause crashafter update schema
app work properly and stores data without any crashes
but when i use app inspector to inspect changes in data base suddenly it crashes with out showing any data or database names etc
heres log of logcat

and database
@Database(
   entities = [RoomModel::class],
   version = 6,
   exportSchema = true
)
abstract class db : RoomDatabase() {

   
   abstract fun SigninDAO(): SigninDAO

   
   companion object {
       @Volatile
       private var INSTANCE: db? = null

       fun getInstance(context: Context): db {
           synchronized(this) {
               var instance = INSTANCE
               if (instance == null) {
                   instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                       context.applicationContext,
                       db::class.java,
                       "localDB"
                   )
                       .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                       .build()

                   INSTANCE = instance
               }
               return instance
           }

       }
   }
}

